# ASP.Net Webform

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, parameters

I've been writing my own music database using a web front end, I found a free to use player called Wimpy, can create my own favourite tracks and save them to an XML file, the player picks up these tracks and plays them.

Have since found the following jQuery script and tweaked it, this is my first attempt with jQuery

```
  <script> 
     function ChangePlaylist () 
     {
        var selected= "MusicFavourites/" + $(ddlFavFolders).val() + ".xml";  
        $("#MyTest").attr("data-media",selected)  
     };  
 </script>
```

My div in the html is

```
            <td class="vtop"><div id="MyTest" runat="server" class="player" data-wimpyPlayer data-media="MusicFavourites/Part 2.xml"></div></td>
```

My C# code is

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, this.GetType(), "script", "ChangePlaylist();", true);
```

I'm trying to update the `Part 2.xml` to Read the dropdown value `Part 1.xml`

Many thanks for your help

Comment: Have got the following jQuery script

Comment: Please re-read your question and add details where possible. As it is right now, it's very hard to follow what you're trying to do and what you're struggling with.